# asp.net website and sql server join to domain

Tags: .net, sql, dns

I have a ASP.NET web application running on a webserver, that uses a database server (the same server). Everything was working fine, until I joined the server to a domain.

The following error happend on the web application:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40)

When I connect to the SQL server via Sql Management Studio localy everything works normal. Is it maybe something in my connectionstring?

Comment: Try to access sqlserver using IP instead of name. Since if you join domain after installing sqlserver the computer name changes and the default instance is not accessible anymore with the name.

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means that either the SQL Server hasn't had [remote connections enabled](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277), or that there is no SQL instance at the location specified in your connection string.

As you have just joined the server to a domain, is it possible that the server name has changed? Are you trying to connect as a user that has the rights to connect?

**Edit:** try using this connection string:

```
database=DB;server=.\[instance name];User Id=sa;Password=PWD;
```

Note the `.\`, and you will need to fill in the default instance name. Also if you have the SQL Browser service turned off then you will not be able to find the default instance unless you explicitly identify it in the connection string (you may be going this already when you connect with SSMS).

Comment: i have romote connections enabled, the computer name is changed, but i tried lots of diferent variations on the connection string: connectionString="Datasource=localhost;Database=DB;User Id=sa;Password=PWD". i connect to the server via SA user, so he has rights. has is something to do with permissions?

Comment: @Vincent - you will need to show us the connection string (blank out sensitive info like the password if it contains one). Also are you using SQL authentication or Windows?

Comment: connectionString="Datasource=localhost;Database=DB;User Id=sa;Password=PWD"

Comment: i connect to the server via SA user, so he has rights. has is something to do with windows permissions you think?? the sql server and the IIS server both run under the local system account. another strange thing is that i CAN connect to the SQL server via a Sql server management studio on my local machine to the sql server.

Comment: hmm, i checked, and the SQL browser is enabled. I to do it your way in the connection string, but still unsuccesful. the problem is only when running the website on the server. If i run the website on my development PC, its all working with the connection string with the servername in it. but as soon as i want to run the website on the production server, i get this error. Maybe something went wrong in the IIS Environment?